# Configuring Serilog Log.Logger at the API service level

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, logging, serilog

I have a logging use case where I want to log a specific API call at a different level than all of the other API services using Serilog, Log.Logger.  My current logger configuration for the application is something like:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(_loggingLevelSwitch)
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, "LogTable")
                .CreateLogger();
```

So, when I call SetLoggingLevelSwitch to update the log level, it updates the level for the entire application, which is expected.  What I'm wondering is, in an individual API call, can I override the log level just for the scope of that API call and not affect the log level in the rest of the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use any Container for registration of common logger and then create ILogger from it

```
services.AddScoped<LoggerConfiguration>((_) => {
new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console();
});
```

Create logger with

```
public YourApiController(LoggerConfiguration loggerOrdinaryConfig)
{
    _strangeApiLogger = loggerOrdinaryConfig.
        MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

But it could lead to difficulties with testing.

That's why you'd better look at [LogContext](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) (with filtering by property) or even [FileConfiguration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-docker/blob/master/web-sample/src/appsettings.json)

upd: Always try to use interfaces because of easier unit testing reasons